# How to display the date in a pdf report in odoo 13?

Tags: odoo, odoo-13

I am creating a custom pdf report in odoo. The custom report should represent the working contract of an employee, based on the odoo contract. For that, I have two files, employee_contract_report.xml and the report file contract.xml. The report is created and most fields are displayed as they should except the start date field and the fields for the working hours and working hour rate. These also are the only fields that I am getting through contract_id and not directly through the employee model. I guess the error lies somewhere there. Does anyone have an idea why this doesn't work? Thanks a lot!

employee_contract_report.xml looks like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <report
            id="report_employee_contract"
            string="Employee Contract"
            model="hr.employee"
            report_type="qweb-pdf"
            name="mycompany.report_employee_contract"
            file="mycompany.report_employee_contract"
    />
</odoo>
```

employee_contract_report.xml looks like this (failing snippet):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <template id="report_employee_contract">
        <t t-call="web.html_container">
            <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
                <t t-call="web.external_layout">

                    <style>
                        .thick {
                        font-weight: bold;
                        }
                    </style>

                    <h1>Leih-Arbeitsvertrag</h1>

                    <div class="page">

                        <!-- Company Informations -->
                        <table id="company-infos" class="table table-sm table-bordered">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <strong>zwischen</strong>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div>
                                        <span t-field="o.company_id.name"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <span t-field="o.company_id.street"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <span t-field="o.company_id.street2" t-if="o.company_id.street2"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <span t-field="o.company_id.city"/>
                                        <span t-field="o.company_id.state_id"/>
                                        <span t-field="o.company_id.zip"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <span t-field="o.company_id.country_id"/>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>

                        <table id="employee-infos" class="table table-sm table-bordered">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <strong>und</strong>
                                </td>

                                <td>
                                    <div>
                                        <span t-field="o.name"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <span t-field="o.address_home_id"/>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>

                    </div>
             
                    <h2>Arbeitsbeginn</h2>
                    <div>
                        Das Arbeitsverhältnis beginnt am<span t-field="o.contract_id.date_start"/>.
                    </div>
                 
                    <h2>Arbeitszeit</h2>
                    <div>
                        Die regelmässige wöchentliche Normalarbeitszeit beträgt
                        <span t-field="o.contract_id.resource_calendar_id.full_time_required_hours"/>
                        Stunden bei einem Anstellungspensum
                        von<span t-field="o.contract_id.resource_calendar_id.work_time_rate"/>.
                    </div>
                </t>
            </t>
        </t>
    </template>
</odoo>
```

This is the output where the start date is missing:

[image]

Comment: Is your test contract "open"? The field `contract_id` will be written when a contract is set to open. So the field could be just empty.

Comment: The code looks fine.

Comment: Ha indeed the contract was not open and running! Best fix ever :) Thanks